# Shrinkage caused by TableForm

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, style

Writing:

```
table = {{Style[
    ToString[Subscript["\[Eta]", "1"], StandardForm] <> " = " <> 
     ToString[a b/2, StandardForm], FontFamily -> "Consolas", 
    FontSize -> 16, Black]}, 
  " ", {Style[
    ToString[Subscript["\[Eta]", "2"], StandardForm] <> " = " <> 
     ToString[c d/2, StandardForm], FontFamily -> "Consolas", 
    FontSize -> 16, Black]}}
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
TableForm[table]
```

I get:

[image]

where it is evident that the fractions are reduced. How can I avoid this shrinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ScriptLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScriptLevel) somewhere. For example:

```
table
TableForm[Style[table, ScriptLevel->0]]
```

[image]

**Update to address comment**

I will include `ScriptLevel->0` in one of your table entries but not the other so you can see the difference.

```
table = {
    {
    Style[
        ToString[Subscript["\[Eta]","1"],StandardForm]<>" = "<>ToString[a b/2,StandardForm],
        FontFamily->"Consolas",FontSize->16,Black, ScriptLevel->0
    ]
    },
    " ",
    {
    Style[
        ToString[Subscript["\[Eta]","2"],StandardForm]<>" = "<>ToString[c d/2,StandardForm],
        FontFamily->"Consolas",FontSize->16,Black
    ]
    }
};

TableForm[table]
```

[image]